# Can I use the Snow Leopard install discs to recover a Mountain Lion Time Machine backup onto a new hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, time-machine, osx-mountain-lion

I'd like to install a new SSD into my 15" mid 2010 MacBook Pro which is currently running Mountain Lion. Previously when I have changed the hard drive I've been able to recover the system using its Time Machine backups and the Snow Leopard install discs.

**Since I have no install discs of Mountain Lion due to downloading it from the App Store, will I be able to use the Snow Leopard discs to transfer the Time Machine backup onto the new hard drive?**